# What are hyphal compartments?

Tags: mycology

The hyphae are the branching filaments that make up the mycelium of a fungus. Hyphal compartments are part of the hyphae. What are they exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick lookup on google for "hyphal compartments" and the number of online texts/books/citations using this term is quite meagre to say the least. One of the images that I found was this-
[image: Septate hyphae]

And I have reached to the conclusion that--

**Hyphae cells (only in septate species) are known as hyphal compartments.**

Quoting from [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypha) (read if you don't know about septate and coenocytic varieties of hyphae)

> A hypha (plural hyphae, from Greek ὑφή, huphḗ, “web”) is a long, branching filamentous structure of a fungus, oomycete, or actinobacterium.In most fungi, hyphae are the main mode of vegetative growth, and are collectively called a mycelium.
>
> A hypha consists of one or more cells surrounded by a tubular cell
> wall. In most fungi, hyphae are divided into cells by internal
> cross-walls called "septa" (singular septum). Septa are usually
> perforated by pores large enough for ribosomes, mitochondria and
> sometimes nuclei to flow between cells. The major structural polymer
> in fungal cell walls is typically chitin, in contrast to plants and
> oomycetes that have cellulosic cell walls. Some fungi have aseptate
> hyphae, meaning their hyphae are not partitioned by septa.
>
> Hyphae have an average diameter of 4-6 µm.

[image: Pic]